# Operação com grande matriz

Tags: r, matriz

Pessoal gostaria de saber como posso fazer a distância euclidiana ao quadrado entre os vetores octadimensionais de `b` e os que não estão em `a` numa super matriz como esta do exemplo.

Pensei assim e não funcionou. Alguém tem uma ideia?

Li a base toda:

```
a = matrix(rnorm(4177*8), ncol = 8)
```

só pra exemplificar peguei os 1000 primeiros:

```
b = a[1:1000, ]
```

A função tira os que são iguais e deixa os diferentes:

```
d = a[!apply(a, 1, function(arow) any(apply(b, 1, function(brow) all(brow==arow)))),]

distancia = t(d - b)%*%(d - b)
```

Mas tenho o seguinte erro:

> Error in d - b : non-conformable arrays

Comment: O erro que você deveria receber não é esse. Sua mensagem de erro possui `C`, e sua matriz tem nome `c`. Além disso, não é uma boa ideia utilizar nomes de funções nativas, especialmente uma como `c()`. Você deveria receber outro erro, em virtude das matrizes `c` e `b` serem de tamanhos diferentes.

Comment: Agora que você editou, o erro já te diz o problema: Você quer subtrair matrizes de tamanhos diferentes, há algo de errado na sua matemática, e não no seu código.

Comment: Estou verificando. Muito grato!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A questão é como definir uma matriz `a` apropriada.

Se usar:

```
N=2000
a = matrix(rnorm(N*2*8), ncol = 8)
#b = a[1:N, ]
#para fazer a questão mais desafiadora pode definir b com linhas aleatórias de a
b = a[sample(2*N,N), ]
```

O seu problema teria solução.